# Spring Cloud: How to use Feign without Ribbon

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-feign

I would like to use Feign without client-side loadbalancer Ribbon because I don't want to run Eureka, which would need to be distributed and highly available. Instead internal ELBs with internal DNS names managed by Route53 will do just fine.

Providing plain URLs to `@FeignClient` always results in `no loadbalancer found for ..`, so I tried preventing Feign from using Ribbon:

Spring Cloud Netflix comes with `FeignRibbonClient`, which is used if `ILoadBalancer` from `ribbon-loadbalancer` is present. However, if this dependency is excluded `FeignConfiguration` is broken:

```
Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'apiVersionClient': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: feign.codec.Decoder org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignConfiguration.decoder; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
```

Ideas welcome :-)

Comment: Why don't you want `ribbon-loadbalancer`?

Comment: I just added some context to the question: It's about Eureka.

Comment: Ribbon does not depend on Eureka. You just have to tell the load balancer where the remote servers are individually (e.g. create a `@RibbonClient` configuration and set the `ServerList` up as a `@Bean`). Which isn't to say that there might not be a bug in Spring Cloud preventing you from doing that easily.

Comment: New docs: http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-feign-without-eureka

Comment: Ok, I didn't try that. But my point is that I don't want to configure lists of servers, I just want to use a plain URL, as I would do using `RestTemplate`.

Comment: Isn't a plain URL just a list with one element? If you have a feature request, then put it in github, please.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to use a plain URL use:

```
@FeignClient(value = "http://example.com", loadbalance = false)
```

With the Brixton release train you would use:

```
@FeignClient(url = "http://example.com", name = "example")
```

Comment: Where does the URL go then?

Comment: Updated answer, it goes in `value`

Comment: @spencergibb `loadbalance` does not seem to be available in `@FeignClient` any more (Spring Boot 1.3.5, Brixton SR1 release). Any alternatives?

Comment: @demaniak If you don't want to loadbalance you use `@FeignClient(url="http://example.com", name="example")`

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb. I also figured out I can disable ribbon with `ribbon.eureka.enabled=false`

Comment: if eureka isn't on the classpath, that would disable it as well.

Comment: Greenwich release don't have attribute 'loadbalance'?

Comment: @spencergibb How do I disable the ribbon loadbalancer if I am building the url dynamically and passing URI object to feign client method call? I don't want to include the `url` attribute in the `@FeignClient` ? More details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61001300/java-spring-feign-errors-out-with-load-balancer-does-not-have-available-server

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat late, but after looking into this if you provide your own Client Bean the LoadBalancerFeignClient wont get built and used, and the Feign open tracing autoconfig will still work.

```
@Bean
public Client feignClient() {
    return new Client.Default(null, null);
}
```