# Java/Spring: Feign errors out with Load Balancer does not have available server for client

Tags: java, spring, rest, feign

I have the following very simple feign client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "user-client", fallbackFactory = UserClientFallbackFactory.class, configuration = MyFeignConfig.class)
public interface UserServiceClient {

    @GetMapping(value = "/users", headers = {"Content-Type: application/json"})
    List<Namespace> getIdentities(URI baseUrl);
}
```

With the following `application.yml`

```
feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: true

hystrix:
    command:
      default:
        execution:
          timeout.enabled: false
          isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests: 100
```

When I invoke the client, I dynamically generate the URL at runtime:

```
client.getIdentities(new URI("http://my-user-service.com"));
```

But this throws the error:

```
com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: my-user-service.com
```

If I manually specify the URL in the client itself(but still pass in a built URI object), the error goes away:

```
@FeignClient(name = "user-client", url = "http://my-user-service.com", fallbackFactory = UserClientFallbackFactory.class, configuration = MyFeignConfig.class)
```

I am using

```
spring-cloud-starter-openfeign
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix
```

With

```
springBootVersion = '2.1.8.RELEASE'
springCloudVersion = 'Greenwich.SR1'
```

Why is this happening? Why do I need to specify the hard-coded URL if I am specifying the URL at runtime ? And what's this load-balancer ? I haven't configured any of that

Comment: The loadbalancer you mentioned is probably Ribbon. And all those, Feign, Hystrix, Ribbon and Eureka are tightly coupled together and require precision when used. Try checking this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401009/load-balancer-does-not-have-available-server-for-client